# How do I sort results from a nested select while keeping the rollup on the last row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I sort the results into the following example by the sellers name while keeping the rollup at the bottom?

Since the the grouping is applied to the nested `SELECT` I can't use `ORDER BY` and since the grouping isn't applied at the top level I can't use the [GROUPING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) either.

[**Click here to see the working example in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1de3d/15)

```
CREATE TABLE Sales 
(
        SellerID    INT
    ,   StoreID     INT
    ,   Price       MONEY
);

CREATE TABLE Sellers 
(
        SellerID    INT
    ,   Name        VARCHAR(50)  
)

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES 
    (1, 1, 100),
    (1, 1, 100),
    (1, 1, 100),
    (2, 2, 200),
    (2, 2, 200),
    (3, 2, 250),
    (3, 2, 250),
    (3, 2, 250),
    (3, 2, 250);

INSERT INTO Sellers VALUES
    (1, 'C. Thirdplace'),
    (2, 'A. Firstplace'),
    (3, 'B. Secondplace');

SELECT  s.Name          AS Seller_Name
    ,   x.TotalSales    AS Total_Sales
FROM 
(  
    SELECT      s.SellerID AS SellerID
            ,   SUM(s.Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM        Sales s 
    GROUP BY    s.SellerID 
    WITH ROLLUP
) x
LEFT JOIN   Sellers s 
ON          s.SellerID = x.SellerID;
```

Which produces the following result:

```
SELLER_NAME      TOTAL_SALES
---------------  -----------
C. Thirdplace        300
A. Firstplace        400
B. Secondplace      1000
(null)              1700
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN seller_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  seller_name
```

Comment: Nice solution! But should it not be opposite 0/1 if the rollup is suppose to be last?

Comment: @altschuler - Sorting is naturally ascending.  This puts NULLs last.

Comment: But here you are ordering by "1, null" if its the rollup and "0, <name>" if its the others, or did i miss something?

Comment: @altschuler - Yes. And as `ORDER BY` defaults to `ASC`, the `0, <name>` records will appear before the `1, NULL` records.